# Why do these python import statements behave differently?

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

Consider the following python package:

```
/pkg
/pkg/__init__.py
/pkg/a.py
/pkg/b.py
```

The a and b modules both depend on each other, and so each must import the other -- a circular dependency.  There appear to be 4 ways to perform this import statement.

Inside **a.py**:

```
import b
```

Inside **b.py** (I'm only using one of these import statements at a time):

```
import a
import pkg.a
from pkg import a
from . import a
```

These import statements are all syntactically different versions of the same import, and yet they don't all work the same.  Trying to import **pkg.a** will produce different results.

```
import a
```

The first import style works without error; though it will fail in python3 or if absolute imports are specified, so I would rather not use a deprecated style.

```
import pkg.a
```

This also works, though it makes the code a bit more verbose, especially when there are additional subpackages.

```
from pkg import a
```

This fails.  `ImportError: cannot import name a`

```
from . import a
```

This also fails with the same error.

Why are these import statements resulting in different behavior?  It seems odd that the last two styles should fail, especially since they appear to be the preferred style going forward.  I'm using python 2.7.

**EDIT:**

To test this create a test.py with the following code:

```
import pkg.a
```

**EDIT:**

Also, if you use the `as` syntax to try and shorten the imported symbol on an import statement that otherwise works, it will also fail, though it will be an `AttributeError`:

```
import pkg.a as a
```

Comment: "These import statements are all syntactically different versions of the same import" is not true, as you can see by the fact, that they behave differently. This is not a "style" question. See here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: @Hyperboreus  The docs you linked seem to indicate that each of these import styles should behave the same, with the exception of the deprecated `import a` style, which behaves differently in python 2 & 3.

Comment: @BrendanAbel: No they don't. `from pkg import a` attempts to import `a` as a top-level name in `b`; `import pkg.a` imports does not. Also, the former works just as well if `a` is something defined directly in `pkg` rather than a submodule, while the latter doesn't. (And of course if `a` is something defined directly in `pkg` and is _also_ the name of a submodule, Python 2.x doesn't even define which one the first one gives you, while the second one is unambiguous.)

Comment: Meanwhile, "fails" or "doesn't work" is a completely useless statement when you're trying to get people to debug your problems. What happens? An exception? Then show the exception. Something kind of "success" that's different than you expected? Then show what you expected and how it was different. And so on.

Comment: @abarnert  I updated the question with the Exception - an ImportError.

Comment: Please give us a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). As you can see from my answer, all four of these work just fine, unless you do something _else_ wrong. So you're asking us to try to guess what other thing you're doing wrong.

Comment: @abarnert I can also duplicate it exactly as stated with `python -m pkg.b`; using either `from` form of importing fails with `ImportError: cannot import name a` while the other two work.  It can be triggered identically with a separate test file as described by the most recent edit, too.

Comment: @abarnert True, if I did have a function or other symbol defined inside either of these modules, the `from x import y` syntax would be able to import it while the `import x.y` style wouldn't.  But I don't have anything else defined in these modules, and the docs seem to indicate that if `from x import y` cannot find a function or symbol defined in x, it will assume y is a module and import it, which should be true in this case, but doesn't appear to work that way.

Comment: @Izkata: But again, the "working" one does not work either, you just aren't going far enough to see that it doesn't work. You need a test that actually _does_ something to see whether it's doing anything.

Comment: @abarnert The circular import still exists, so why isn't there an `ImportError`?

Comment: Is there any code in your `__init__.py` file? Could it have something to do with the errors you're getting?

Comment: @Blckknght No, there is nothing in `__init__.py`

Comment: @Izkata: Because you're in the middle of importing `b`, and whether `pkg` exists yet is undefined in Python 2. All four versions are broken and unusable; if you want to know exactly why each one breaks in a particular version of a particular implementation, you can either trace the sequence of import steps, or read the source code, but it doesn't matter. (If this question were about Python 3, where the entire process has been redesigned and is fully defined and documented, that would be a different story. Still not very _useful_, but at least answerable.)

Comment: @abarnert That first sentence is probably the answer, especially if you can expand on it a bit more